# Timeout an MS Access ComObject from powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, vba

I have a powershell script that creates an MS Access ComObject and uses it to run a macro in an MS Access database as shown below:

$AccessDb= New-Object -ComObject Access.Application

```
try{ 

 foreach($file in $Files)
  { 
    ...
    $AccessDb.DoCmd.RunMacro('mcrScr')
    ...
 }

}
catch { ... }
```

The issue is when there are runtime errors, MS Access throws the errors in an interactive window or dialog box and this causes the powershell to hang; just waiting for the window to close and thus macros for other .mdb files do not get to run. 
I have been trying out options from online articles to timeout this piece of my code  $AccessDb.DoCmd.RunMacro('mcrScr'), if it runs more than x number of seconds. I used jobs, runspace and [system.diagnostics.stopwatch] but have not been successful.
Is there any better approach to do this. I am kind of running out of options.

Edit:
@Paul, in response to your comment I am adding how i am using runspace to address the problem.

```html
function Script-Timeout {
    param([scriptblock]$Command,[int]$Timeout)

    $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $Runspace.Open()

    $PS = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Command)
    $PS.Runspace = $Runspace

    $chk = $PS.BeginInvoke()
    if($chk.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($Timeout))
    {
     $PS.EndInvoke($chk)
    }
    else
    {
       
       throw "Command taking too long to run. Timeout exceeded." 
       $PS.EndInvoke($chk)
    }


}
```

The Script-Timeout function is then used in the portion of my script that runs the MS Acess macro as shown below:

```html
Try{
    forEach($mdbfile in Files)
    {
        ...
        Script-Timeout -Command {
             $AccessDb= New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
            $AccessDb.OpenCurrentDatabase($mdbfile)

            $AccessDb.DoCmd.RunMacro('mcrUpdate') 

            $AccessDb.CloseCurrentDatabase() 
            } -Timeout 20
        ...    
     }
 }
 catch
 {
  #catch exception
 }
```

I have artificially created a runtime error in the VBA which throws an error dialog box. This way the RunMacro portion of the script, if it gets run, will hung the powershell. This is where i expect the runspace to timeout the macro run from powershell after x seconds.
The problem with runspace is that the MS Access Macro does not get run at all. In powershell debug mode, i see the if-block of the script-timeout function always execute successfully with or without the  artificial runtime error

Comment: Did you try using `DoCmd.SetWarnings` to false?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: so what was the problem with runspaces? you could just dispose it after a certain timespan

Comment: @SmrtGrunt DomCmd.SetWarnings in VBA does not hide runtime errors from being displayed as dialog box

Comment: @HansonHackman Thanks - I was under the impression that it killed all popups.